# How much better (as a percentage) is $A$ than $B$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

This may sound stupid, but is it correct to say

> $100$ is a hundred percent *better* than $50$

where by *better* I mean *higher* or something like that. Similarly would it be correct to ask questions like, "How much *better* is $50$ than $30$?" and, "How much *worse* is $30$ than $50$?"

Comment: When one speaks of percents, it is generally imagined that there is a "whole" that you are comparing to.  In that sense, $100\%$ means the whole thing, $50\%$ means half the thing (and $200\%$ means two of the thing).  "better" is subjective...probably not a useful concept here.

Comment: "Better" as in "$A$ is better than $B$", by wording, is a binary relation. So for question "How "better" is 50 than 30?" answer is "50 is truly better than 30".

Comment: Use *bigger/smaller* instead. Still, this is one of the ambiguties in language (not just english), you can interpret it as multiplication (200 is 200% of 100) or addition (200 is 100% larger than 100). Use this in conversation, but in text, prefer more precise expressions.

Comment: I've edited your question quite a bit. Please read it to make sure it still captures the intent of your original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words "*better*" and "*worse*" are inherently subjective, so using them in a mathematics question here will get some cringes. Also whether or not the words "*better*" and "*worse*" are correct to use in a situation depends on what the percentages represent. Certainly $100\%$ is better than $50\%$ if you are talking about exam scores, but it is certainly worse if you are talking about how much of a population is afflicted with a disease. Instead let's use objective words like "*more*" and "*less*".

From your example, $100$ is *more than* $50$. It is exactly twice $50$, so you could say either of the phrases:

- $100$ is $200\%$ **of** $50$.
- $100$ is $100\%$ **more than** $50\%$ (because $100\%$ **of** $50$ is $50$ and you need $100\%$ **more** to get to $100$).

For the $50$ and $30$ example, first we need to note that $50/30 \approx 1.67 = 167\%$. Similar to the previous example we can say either of the following phrases:

- $50$ is $167\%$ **of** $30$.
- $50$ is $67\%$ **more than** $30\%$ (because $100\%$ **of** $30$ is $30$ and you need $67\%$ **more** to get to $50$).

If you really wanted to, you could arrive at this "$67\%$ more" figure directly by looking at how much more than $30$ do we need to get to $50$. That is, look at $(50-30)/30 = 20/30$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your question, but I would suggest that $\frac{A}{B}$ is your answer.

This would tell us that 100 is twice as good as 50, and that 50 is $\frac{5}{3}$ better than 30.

Comment: I think $A/B-1$ is a better answer. Because B is A plus "this much" times A.